# Virtual Desktop on WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I have just started playing with virtual desktops.  They do everyting I want, except

1. I would like them persistent across reboots.
2. And I would like to have startup apps pinned to particular desktops.

Is there any software that will do this ?  I don't mind paying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recomment **[VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/)** for this, which I'm using myself for years whenever I'm forced to work on a Windows machine (grin). VirtuaWin …

- supports Win9x/ME/NT/Win2K/XP/Win2003/Vista/Win7/Win10
- can pin applications to desktops (see first screenshot below)
- runs stable and reliable (I've used it with Windows XP, Vista, and Windows 7 and no issues)
- is even available as "portable app" (not requiring installation, usable in "user mode" without admin privileges)
- lets you send applications from one desktop to another, have them on a single or on all desktops
- has no problems using multiple monitors (I use it succesfully with two and expanded desktop)
- lets you use keyboard or mouse to switch desktops, define other hotkeys as well
- gives you no need to mind paying, it's GPL ([open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source))

[image: Window Rules] [image: Settings]
<sup>*VirtuaWin* screenshots (source: [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

[image: Desktop indicator]
<sup>Desktop indicator</sup>

Comment: Just trying it now, looks great.

Comment: *Feels* great, too :) Enjoy – and when satisfied, please accept the answer :)

Comment: There's a module for Virtua Win called VWDesktopIcons that will let you show icons on your choice of VDesktops.

Comment: @TecBrat there are [many modules for VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/?page_id=50). I'm just not sure if they all still work, or which are still maintained – and for some, if they even still exist (those linked to GoogleCode seem to have disappeared, not sure where to).

Comment: I just upgraded to w10 and my the module still works.

Comment: Thanks! Wish we knew for the others. Some seem not updated for 10+ years,

Comment: Does VirtuaWin allow for individual windows of an application to be pinned to different desktops? I have different projects on different (Win10 native) virtual desktops right now, each with a set of browser windows, word and excel documents etc. If this is application based, would it put (for example) all excel documents on the same virtual desktop after a reboot?

Comment: @MiG as far as I remember yes (haven't used it lately and no Windows machine to check).

Comment: Thanks! I currently only have the one Win10 machine and it's in heavy use, so I'm hoping someone can confirm this before I mess with its setup :)

Comment: @Izzy Just to be clear, the 'yes' is on piling all windows of a single application onto a single virtual desktop? Or about being able to pin these to different desktops?

Comment: @MiG AFAIR the latter – but it's been 6 years since I last used it, so I cannot give any guarantees. As the software is free to use: why not simply try it and let us know? Fastest way to get a reliable answer to that, wouldn't you agree? ;)

Comment: As mentioned this laptop is in very heavy use, so I'm reluctant to even hibernate it (I've regularly lost sessions before) or do reboots, let alone make these kinds of modifications... Hence my question :)

Comment: @MiG - I use it regularly.  The answer is  - probably not. I dont have any problems with the browsers.  Ditto for Beyond Compare.  But they are running separate sessions.  I tried two IDEs - Embarcadero Delphi and Webuilder.  For both the windows go together, when you shift desktops.