# Multiple desktops on multi-screen Windows 7 with one screen keeping the same desktop all the time

Tags: gratis, windows-7, multi-monitor, virtual-desktop

I'm looking for a piece of software that will make me able to use multiple desktops on Windows 7, but in a special way: I use two screens and I want to change desktops at only one of them (the other one should keep the same windows all the time). Right now I'm using Desktops 2.0, but it lacks the feature I'm looking for. Free-for-commercial-use applications are more than welcome.

Comment: Do you really need one entire screen to stick – or would it be sufficient if you can define a window being visible on all virtual desktops? The latter works fine here for me with e.g. having Firefox open at the left monitor regardless on what virtual desktop I'm switching to.

Comment: That could actually be the answer - I'll give it a try. Can you provide me more info?

Comment: Sure. See my answer on [Virtual Desktop on WIndows 10](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28479/185) :) I'm using that on Windows 7 in the office.