# Search bar for opened windows on Windows

Tags: windows, search

For keyboard oriented people ALT + TAB is still an unhappy solution when you have tons of windows open, even more when the windows are on multiple desktops.

Today, the fastest way to move around is with instant search.

- As a developer, you can use a code completion tool or search for file or a relevant code instantly in a modern IDE with a single shortcut showing results instantly like this:

  [image]
- If you want to search for an opened tab in chrome, you use omnibar, or vimium like this:

  [image]
- If you are looking for files on PC, you can use Everything search and it shows files that match your wording instantly:

  [image]

Navigation with filtering by typing the parts of the name are just the fastest.
What I would like to have is a similar search bar to navigate between opened windows, to avoid alt-tabbing like crazy and wasting time searching for the right window on the right desktop. There has got to be something like that out there, but I do not even know what keywords to use to look for it.

I would expect to look inside the title of the window + the name of the software. Typing chrome would open a chrome window. Typing hip would sugges hipchat. If the software could read names of tabs inside of the softs would be an amazing plus, but it need not be. (e.g. tabs of chrome, sublime, notepad++, jabber chat tabs, hipchat tabs...)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: As you're mentioning "multiple desktops": I'm using [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) on my office PC (see also [my answer here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/28481/185)). A left-click on its tray icon lists all open windows from all desktops 3 columns: [switch to/move here/always show](https://i.imgur.com/KgPSNjh.png). Would that meet your needs?

Comment: I would have to try the software out (and I will, I am currently unhappy with Win 10 desktop managment and Dexpot is unfortunately paid and has a serious bug, so I am open to new software). However, what I am looking for is specifically a search bar inititated by a key shortcut. Shortcut -> type few letters -> enter -> Boom, you have your window. Your suggestoin is based on clicking and searching with eyes. I usually have 20-40 windows open (huge ram, complicated workflow, not counting tabs in browsers and other software) So mouse and eyes is not what I am looking for.

Comment: "Your suggestoin is based on clicking and searching with eyes": Not necessarily. One-time "clicking" (right button, then "setup", then tab "hotkeys"), configure your hotkey ("UI: Open compact window list"), save. What then remains is "searching with the eyes", granted – I could not find a "search" function, but neither felt the need for it (usually have less than 20 windows open, though some of them (browser, terminals) are tabbed).

Comment: Shortcut option sounds nice. It is quite similar to ALT + Tab still, without the problem of having to search windows in different desktops. Your suggestion will be useful to many and to me too, but it is not really fully what I was asking for, so I would not accept it as an answer. Thanks though, it is still very useful!

Comment: Yupp, agreed – exactly why I've made it a comment and not an answer: it doesn't *fully* match, and the missing part is an essential requirement of yours. Good luck with better hits then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it was right here and I did not see it. In [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/), the software I really like, (free for private use), you can use a shortcut called "Find window"

It opens up this:
[image]
and it defaults into the search bar - exactly what I needed.

Thanks, dexpot. You never stop surprising me. Too bad you have [this bug](http://dexpot.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=5916) that you still didn't fix...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the application [Switcheroo](http://www.switcheroo.io/) 

It works like Launchy but is a bit too slow for my liking.
[image]

One more alternative is an Autohotkey script [ISwitchW](https://github.com/tvjg/iswitchw) it works like charm

[image]